# Using an appropriate article before the word "leadership"

Tags: grammaticality, articles

I had a quick question. Recently a co-worker posted a how-to guide entitled "How to be a good leadership at work". To me the sentence seems incorrect. But I can't explain why. Technically leadership is a noun, just like in the sentence "How to be a good person at work" would be correct, because person is also a noun.

Perhaps it's one of those things that sounds incorrect to me but really is correct. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the verb not the noun. So, while you can **be** a good person or a good leader, you cannot **be** a good leadership. Similarly, you can be a good friend but not be a good friendship. The sentence can be rewritten as:

- How to be a good leader at work.

or

- How to demonstrate good leadership at work.

Comment: Oh I do understand that, intuitively, at least. But the word leadership is, by definition, a noun. Effectively interchanging the word "leadership" with another noun makes it correct. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with "leadership" generally referring to more than one person, or a collection. Are there any specific rules with article use and counted nouns?

Comment: @Bob, I may have misinterpreted your question. It seems that the issue here is that leadership can have two meanings. Firstly, it can mean the people who are in control of a company, and secondly, it can refer to the qualities that make someone a good leader. I assumed you were using it in the second sense. As to its first sense, I guess it is as possible to say "*How to be a good leadership*" as to say "*How to be a good committee*" or "*How to be a good government*", since all three are collective nouns. It still sounds a little odd to me, however.

Comment: Yes it does sound strange to me. Essentially, what I'm asking is, based on the sentence alone (since I'm unclear of the writer's intent) is there a technical/grammatical reason why this sentence is incorrect? Or, is it correct technically and is just forever doomed to sound strange to me?

Comment: @Bob, If *leadership* is interpreted as a collective noun, then it is grammatically correct to refer to "a good leadership", as in: "*Every successful company needs a good leadership.*" So, yes, *How to be a good leadership* is grammatical too.

Comment: thanks. Although it sounds super weird, I suppose I'll have to try and not let it bother me. I've marked the above answer correct then. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not the leadership, but the article "a". If you wanted to say what you wanted to say, it would be

> How to be good leadership at work.

This means, how would you become the trait "leadership" at work, and it can poetically have the intended meaning. There is such a thing as leadership, but it is a non-count noun "much leadership", not "many leadership", and so cannot be "a leadership", but just "leadership".

The count/non-count distinction is missing in other languages, so it might be a much confusing.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Not sure why people down-voted you though. I think the person above already gave me the answer I was looking for. But thanks for the help. STILL sounds weird to me, but technically it's right.

Comment: @Bob: It's right only in a different usage of the word "leadership", where "the leadership" is a noun meaning a bunch of leaders. Then "I am a leadership" means I am a bunch of people. This is the reason I was downvoted--- because I did not recognize the alternate meaning of leadership, which might as well be an entirely different word. The answer I give is correct for the meaning of "leadership" in the meaning you gave originally. I didn't change the meaning at any point. It might also be downvoted because I tend to piss ignorant people off, and that's ok, I'm used to it.